# Filter oembeds tags to modify iframe attributes

Tags: filters, oembed

By default, when putting another WP url inside a post/page, it oEmbeds it and produces a blockquote and iframe code with the default in the front-end:

```
<iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" ....></iframe>
```

It also produces an error in the JS console `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/js/test.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` which is hinting that it is blocking some scripts to run.

What is the best filter to use to modify the iframe produced in the front-end, for example, we want it to `allow-same-origin` attribute for `sandbox`

```
<iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" security="restricted" ....></iframe>
```

Comment: Note that the iframe itself is provided by the OEmbed provider, it isn't always generated by WordPress itself, modifying the result may not be the best approach here, especially if the embedded item is a WP post, modifying the generated oembed iframe for WP embeds at the source end would be better.

Comment: But more importantly, what problem does this solve? Why didn't you ask about that instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response @TomJNowell. Along with my issue is there is an error in JS console `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/js/test.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` I updated this question to add more details to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the the CORS issue by using this snippet which now allows this iFrame to `allow-same-origin` or runs scripts inside this domain.

```
function oembed_iframe_overrides($html, $url, $attr) {

   if ( strpos( $html, "<iframe" ) !== false ) { 
      return str_replace('<iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"', '<iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox', $html); }
   else {
      return $html;
   }
} 
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'oembed_iframe_overrides', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Any help here on a similar question please? :) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339370/wrap-wordpress-site-in-iframe

Comment: Note that `embed_oembed_html` filter is applied *after* retrieving the oEmbed cache, for each embed, so it will have a negative impact on page performance, specially if there are lots of embeds. To prevent this, use the `oembed_result` filter, which is applied before the oEmbed response is cached.